# How to use loop to insert records of data into table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert

I would like to insert a couple of records using PL/SQL loops, but when I execute below block in SQL Developer I am getting the following error:

```
declare
    loop_size number;

begin
    loop_size := 10;

    while loop_size > 0
    loop
        INSERT INTO CM.CUSTOMER (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, STATUS )
        VALUES (CM.SQ_CUSTOMER.nextval, 'Jhon', 'Jhon',10);

        loop_size := loop_size -1;      
    end loop;
end;
```

**Error**

```
PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'CM' reference is out of scope
```

Comment: What do you think `CM` is? A schema? What user runs this?

Comment: yes, it is schema.

Comment: So will you be running this as another user? Generally it is best practice not to hardcode schema names unless you really have to. I would prefer to leave out the schema name and run it from the `CM` account. (By the way, you have a `status` variable but you don't use it. Is it a sting or a number?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your error, but one problem is that `CM.CUSTOMER` can't be both a table and a sequence.

Generally it is best practice not to hardcode schema names unless you really have to. I would prefer to leave out the schema name here and just run it from the `CM` account.

I created a sequence named `customer_seq` and the following runs without error:

```
create table customer
( id          number primary key 
, first_name  varchar2(20)
, last_name   varchar2(20)
, status      number );

create sequence customer_seq;

declare
    status varchar(10) := '10';
    loop_size number := 10;
begin
    while loop_size > 0
    loop
        insert into customer (id, first_name, last_name, status)
        values (customer_seq.nextval, 'Jhon', 'Jhon', status);

        loop_size := loop_size -1;      
    end loop;
end;
/
```

If using Oracle 12.1 or later I would prefer to use an identity column and stop micro-managing sequences. You also don't need to manage the loop index yourself as PL/SQL has a convenient `for` loop construct:

```
create table customer
( id          number generated always as identity primary key 
, first_name  varchar2(20)
, last_name   varchar2(20)
, status      number );

declare
    status varchar(10) := '10';
    loop_size number := 10;
begin
    for i in 1..loop_size loop
        insert into customer (first_name, last_name, status )
        values ('Jhon', 'Jhon', status);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Good spot that the OP had used `CM.CUSTOMER` for both table and sequence name.

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve this without dynamic SQL:

```
INSERT INTO CM.CUSTOMER (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, STATUS)
SELECT 'Jhon', 'Jhon', '10'
FROM dual
CONNECT BY rownum <= 10;
```

This answer assumes that the `ID` column be auto increment, which it probably should be.

Comment: Umm, in the OP's version value of `STATUS` is `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove last unnecessary commas and select sequence from dual:

```
  INSERT INTO CM.CUSTOMER (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, STATUS)
  select ln.SQ_CUSTOMER, 'Jhon', 'Jhon', 10 from dual;
```

update to sequence to `ln.SQ_CUSTOMER`

Comment: That won't work, Either remove VALUES, or remove SELECT & FROM DUAL.

Comment: Also `CM.CUSTOMER` can't be both a table and a sequence.

Comment: @user7294900, it seems, doesn't recognize schema `ln`, I get the following error: `PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'LN' reference is out of scope`

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your responses, finally I solved my problem as bellow:

```
declare
loop_size number;
rec_id NUMBER;

begin
  loop_size := 10;

  while loop_size > 0
  loop

    execute immediate 'select cm.SQ_CUSTOMER.nextval from dual' into rec_id;

    INSERT INTO CM.CUSTOMER (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, STATUS )
    VALUES (rec_id, 'Jhon', 'Jhon',10);

    loop_size := loop_size -1;      
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: See my updated answer without using `execute immediate`

Comment: Why are you using `execute immediate` for the (pre-12c style) sequence? (And why is it in a different schema from the table?) You can just assign it like your other variables: `rec_id := sq_customer.nextval`. Or better, just use it directly in the `insert` statement with no need for any intermediate variable. Or even better, use an identity column and forget about sequences (see my answer).